# window.GetAnimationFrame() Is not calling callback function

Tags: javascript, canvas, typescript, requestanimationframe

I am doing this in TypeScript but I will post the compiled `Javascript` as well if it helps. The following is my `loop()` function:

`TypeScript`

```
private loop() {
    if(this._running) {
        // input, updating, and rendering
        // ...

        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop);
    }
}
```

`JavaScript`

```
PotatoEngine.prototype.loop = function () {
    var _this = this;
    if (this._running) {
        // input, updating, and rendering
        // ...

        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () { return _this.loop; });
    }
};
```

This code is called from the following `init()` function:

`TypeScript`

```
private init() {
    this._lastTime = Date.now();
    this._running = true;

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop);
}
```

`JavaScript`

```
PotatoEngine.prototype.init = function () {
    var _this = this;
    this._lastTime = Date.now();
    this._running = true;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () { return _this.loop; });
};
```

When I debug and it gets to the `requestAnimationFrame()`, it never goes into the `loop()` function. It just exits out of `init()`. Why?

Comment: You aren't calling `this.loop` at anytime.

Comment: `window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop);` At the bottom of `init()`/`loop()`. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You aren't calling it, you are just returning the function.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` is like an event, return values are not used anywhere. You can either return a reference from an IIFE, or call `_this.loop` in the passed argument function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop);
```

To:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
```

This will actually call `this.loop`. You'll also be able to keep the context thanks to the bind.